# How to use unallocated space in a triple-boot partition scheme?

Tags: partitioning

I am running with triple booting my system.  I have a 1TB drive. I made the error of making the linux swap out of my 600gb ntfs drive, which then it made the space unallocated and I cannot seem to add it to the extended partition.  Is there an easy way to fix this?  I don't mind having to start over the installs, would like to keep the win7 partition so that I can still access the computer. 
**setup**:

> /dev/sda1 - ntfs - 100MB - boot
>
> /dev/sda2 - ntfs - win7 - 218.52GB
>
> /dev/sda3 - ntfs - win8 -  58.59GB
>
> /dev/sda4 - extended - lba - 61.25GB
>
> /dev/sda5 - ext4 - / - 53.71
>
> /dev/sda6 - linux-swap - 8GB
>
> unallocated - 593.05GB

Did not know if I could just shift the linux swap to not be a primary so that I could allocate the 600GB.  Just want to use that drive as NTFS for disc images and media storage.  My guess is that I will have to boot with GParted and delete my Ubuntu Install and repartition those drives, might even have to remove the windows 8 too?  Not sure, can someone give me a partition layout that will work for my triple boot with a media partition as well with all the swaps needed?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the extended partition `sda4` contains `sda5` and `sda6`, since it is roughly the sum of their sizes.

Since Ubuntu (`sda5`) is inside the extended partition (`sda4`), you will not be able to modify the extended partition from your install of Ubuntu. You will need to boot from a LiveCD/USB and use GParted from there.

As far as I know you should just then be able to increase the extended partition (`sda4`) to fill the unallocated space, and then create a new NTFS partition within the extended space. It should not be necessary to change any existing installation, assuming they're all working at the moment.

Note that Ubuntu will work quite happily without swap space (providing you delete the `UUID=xxxxxxx none swap sw 0 0` line in `/etc/fstab` so it doesn't get unhappy being unable to find it on boot), providing you have sufficient RAM.

Comment: Thanks chronitis, I did the fstab edit and removed the swap, then booted with Partition Magic, the liveCD still had some of the partitions locked?  But working great now, thanks.